# Can you include C++ snippets in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net-4.0

Can I include sections of code written in Visual C++ in my C# app, or vise-versa? I know that you can do that in Objective-C, so I wanted to know if it was possible in C# (.NET 4.0).

Answer (score 4):

Sort of. You can't include them directly in C#, but you can use C# and C++/CLI together, and *most* C++ can also be compiled as C++/CLI.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have C++ DLLs?  If so, you can call C++ DLLs from within C#.  There are a few questions on StackOverflow that discuss similar topics:

[How do I use a C++ library from C# and .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579156/how-do-i-use-a-c-library-from-c-and-net)

DllImport can be used to indicate the unmanaged code you want to call.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.  You can create a DLL from C++ code and call said code from C#, though.

See: [Forum thread](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/csharp-programming/102504-mixing-cplusplus-csharp-within-program.html) on related topic, and [an introduction to managed C++](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/01/13/intromcpp.html).  There's also an example of mixing C++ / C# [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/05/20/599434.aspx), although it uses the command line to build the code.